# MVC3 routing confusion

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I want to be able to access the following through one route constraint declaration:

```
/picks                        
/picks/{teamID}/{week}        
/picks/save/{teamID}/{week}
```

This does not work for the second request: `/picks/{teamID}/{week}`

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "picks",
  "picks/{action}/{teamID}/{week}",
  new { controller = "Picks", 
        action = "Index", 
        teamID = UrlParameter.Optional, 
        week = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

It seems to me the action should be defaulted to `Index` since I don't supply one, but I'm assuming it's actually trying to find the action `{teamID}` (which is a number).

How do I make this constraint handle all 3 scenarios?

Comment: Not completely, it doesn't handle all the scenarios I described.

Comment: perhaps something more detailed then `Not completely` would help me help you

Comment: @Eonasdan sorry I don't have the code in front of me so I don't have exact details, I just know it didn't handle all the routes I specified in the original question, I had to make 2 separate rules similar to what *rcdmk* suggested

Comment: you might check Phil Haacks route debugger tool. it's pretty awesome for troubleshooting such issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to omit the action from the rout string for the first route:

```
routes.MapRoute( 
    "picks", 
    "picks/{teamID}/{week}", 
    new { controller = "Picks",  
            action = "Index",  
            teamID = UrlParameter.Optional,  
            week = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Remember to place more specific routes on top of more generic ones.

Eg:

```
"picks/{teamID}/{week}"
"picks/{action}/{teamID}/{week}"
"{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

The routes are tryed in the order they are added.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Phill Haack [route debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx).

You can also add constraints so that the `teamId` will only be picked up if it's a number

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "picks",
  "picks/{action}/{teamID}/{week}",
  new
  {
      controller = "Picks",
      action = "Index",
      teamID = UrlParameter.Optional,
      week = UrlParameter.Optional
  },
  new { teamID = @"\d+" });
```

Comment: Its showing synatx error. where to place `new {teamID = @"\d+"};` ?